# I am having trouble putting a menu bar above a Canvas widgit using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to add a menu bar on a Canvas widget.  I am currently testing it using some demo code I found online, before I implement it in an application that I am writing.  Currently the code shows the window, but the Menu bar appears at the bottom of the page, instead of the top.

Also more of a side note: Is there a way that I can use a function in a seperate python file to draw a shape without having it create an entire new window?

my code:

---

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def option():
     print("Options")

top = Tk()
mb = Menubutton(top, text = "condiments", relief = RAISED)
C = Canvas(top, bg = "blue", height = 250, width = 250)
C.grid()
mb.grid()

mb.menu = Menu(mb, tearoff = 0)
mb["menu"] = mb.menu
mb.menu.add_command(label = "mayo", command = option)
mb.menu.add_command(label = "ketchup", command = option)

coord = 10,50.240, 210
coord1 = 10,50,20,60
arc = C.create_arc(coord, start = 0, extent = 150, fill = "red")
line = C.create_line(coord, fill = "white")
oval = C.create_oval(coord1, fill = "black")

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: change the order of griding - `mb.grid()` before `C.grid()` - to get the menu bar on top

Comment: oh I feel like a fool.  Thanks for the help!  I had swapped the declaration statements for mb and C and i forgot to look at the .grid() statements.   This really helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, grid will automatically increase the row and column unless you specify otherwise. You could also simply reorder the code so that the defaults match up with your expectation.

The Zen of Python says that "explicit is better than implicit". If you explicitly define the row and column, the code will be easier to understand and you can put the menubar wherever you want.

```
mb.grid(row=0, column=0)
C.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Comment: So If i were to have toolbars with buttons, I would put the buttons on rows 1 and 2, and then canvas on the third?

Comment: @BrandonMenge: you can put anything you want on any row that you want.